# Custom price calculation in Woocommerce product page

Tags: woocommerce, product, code-snippets, price

I want to do a simple calculation based-on the price of each product and show it on Woocommerce product page. I need to add a code as snippet or directly in the product page template. But I am not a programmer.

How can I get the products price and do a very simple calculation like divide by 12 + 200 and then show it under the price as a finance option.

The new price is just an information and no need to have the option to be added the cart. I want to make it simple.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a blatant request for someone to write code for a non-programmer!

Comment: @TonyHinkle Some times non programers become programers learning with time, if we give them a chance and if we will drive them to right paths.